How to use interval inside ngOnInit
I want to make a tick in app. So I decided to use interval and subscribe to it inside ngOnInit.
But in that case app will load endlessly, until interval completes (until i'll complete).
How to make a tick without the problem?
code example:
tick$ = interval(500);

ngOnInit() {
    this.tick$.subscribe(console.log);
}


Interval never completes. Subscribing to it inside ngOnInit should not block per se. I believe you have to post some code in order for anyone to help here.

It's happening due to the Angular app having SSR enabled. In SSR, the server waits for the ngOnInit to complete, which does not happen is my understanding of the problem.
One way is to turn of SSR, else you can just move the code to afterRender or afterNextRender this will make the code execute only on the browser:
tick$ = interval(500);

ngAfterViewInit() {
    afterNextRender(() => {
        this.tick$.subscribe(console.log);
    });
}

The above method works for Angular 17+, if you have an older version of Angular then go for the below method:
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Component(...)
export class SomeComponent {
  isBrowser: boolean;
  tick$ = interval(500);


  constructor( @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      if(this.isBrowser) {
          this.tick$.subscribe(console.log);
      }
  }
}

